# How to prevent rebuilding of Symfony cache in each request in test environment

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

I have Symfony 3.3/3.4 and since at some time my functional tests have started to work very slowly. Tests which took 10 minutes started to take 1 hour and more.

We use these packages:

```
"symfony/symfony": "^3.4",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.9",
"doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
"symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
"jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.4",
"jms/di-extra-bundle": "^1.9",
"firebase/php-jwt": "^4.0",
"snc/redis-bundle": "^2.0",
"graylog2/gelf-php": "^1.5",
"noiselabs/smarty-bundle": "^2.0",
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
"eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "^7.3",
"aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony": "^2.0",
"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
"php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle": "^1.14",
"aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator": "^1.1",
"nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
"symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.1",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^7.3",
"dms/dms-filter-bundle": "^4.0",
"tiendanube/php-sdk": ">=1.0",
"liuggio/statsd-client-bundle": "1.6.*",
"instamojo/instamojo-php": "^0.3.0",
"pagarme/pagarme-php": "^3.6",
"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^5.0",
"payprocessing/atol-online": "^1.0",
"paymentwall/paymentwall-php": "^2.2",
"yandex-money/yandex-checkout-sdk-php": "^1.0",
"stripe/stripe-php": "^6.4",
"okapon/doctrine-set-type-bundle": "^0.5.0",
"phpoffice/phpword": "^0.15",
"cloudconvert/cloudconvert-php": "^2.2",
"cleentfaar/slack-bundle": "^0.20.1"
```

Our tests are extended from our base test class `AbstractKernelTestCase`. This class extends base Symfony class `WebTestCase`.

We frequently use JMSDiExtraBundle for DI and declaring services, but now we try to avoid of using it and use native autowire/autoconfigure and others.

I found out with help XDebug that Symfony does compile of cache of containers/bundles almost every request because of `ConfigCache` thinks that the cache of `EntityManager` is obsoleted. I tried to understand how that cache system works but I didn't manage. Cache file of `EntityManager` is wrapped in `Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\ClassExistenceResource` and I can't understand the idea of `isFresh` method. Other files uses other implementations of `Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\SelfCheckingResourceInterface`.

If somebody has an idea - welcome!

```
// Some methods were cut, because they don't give any useful information.
abstract class AbstractKernelTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    /** @var Client */
    protected static $routerClient;

    /** @var BufferedOutput */
    private $errorBuffer;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::$routerClient = self::createClient();
        $this->errorBuffer = new BufferedOutput();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->clearMemory();
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function getRouterClient()
    {
        return self::$routerClient;
    }

    protected function clearMemory(): void
    {
        $reflectionObject = new \ReflectionObject($this);
        foreach ($reflectionObject->getProperties() as $prop) {
            if (!$prop->isStatic() && strpos($prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName(), 'PHPUnit_') === false) {
                $prop->setAccessible(true);
                $prop->setValue($this, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [discussion at github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23165#issuecomment-609360581).

Basically you should:

- as proposed earlier - do not use jms/di-extra-bundle or any bundle depending on it (like jms/security-extra-bundle in our case)
- do not use autowire (actually I would encourage to use autowire and choose another way)
- do not run tests (and probably symfony under PPM/RoadRunner) with enabled "debug" flag, like in a production environment build cache manually and then run tests
- disable di-extra-bundle [integration with doctrine](https://www.jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/doctrine), this might be the easies one